# Challenge: the best way to select the two most similar/closest numbers in a set?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Say you have a set of 4 or more unordered numbers and you are only interested in the 2 numbers nearest or closest to each other. The others are discarded (lets say they are bad measurements). E.g.

```
3.1
5
2.9
1
```

Only 3.1 and 2.9 would be of interest. I used cumbersome formulae to first subtract each element from every other (which only works for a dataset of 4), then pick the smallest difference, then MATCH the smallest difference to the correct difference pair.

Any better way to do it, perhaps with a sort or stats function? Especially if you have more than 4 data points.

Comment: Do you mean to extract the smallest subtraction value between the two?

Comment: To "extract the smallest subtraction value" is only a means to end, which is to determine which pair of numbers are most similar / lies closest to each other on the number line.

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: make a 4x4 grid, minus each number from each number, wrap it in ABS(), then your smallest number shows your closest pair

Comment: @Ron's answer is the ultimate answer. However, bragging rights goes to anyone who can come up with a single line formula for Office 2016 or older for a fixed dataset of only 4 numbers.

Comment: How about for an unlimited number of numbers?  See my edit. It uses the same algorithm.

Comment: Ron delivered! Bragging rights earned. Thanks Ron!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Office 365, you can use the following:

*note that if there are multiple closest pairs, this will return only the pair with the lowest absolute value. If this is a problem, a different formula could be devised*

```
=LET(x,SORT(myRange),
          y,COUNT(x)-1,
          z,INDEX(x,SEQUENCE(y-1,,2)),
          a,INDEX(x,SEQUENCE(y-1)),
          b,z-a,
          c,MATCH(MIN(b),b,0),
          INDEX(x,SEQUENCE(2,,c)))
```

- Sort the range
- Subtract each pair starting with row2 - row1

  - since range is sorted, result will always be positive
- Determine the smallest difference
- Return the matching pair

*If you do not have Office 365 with those functions, you could write a very complicated formula; use multiple helper columns to achieve the same results; or write a VBA UDF.*

[image]

If you have multiple pairs meeting the criteria, to return **ALL** of them, try this formula:

```
=LET(x,SORT(myRange),
          y,COUNT(x)-1,
          z,INDEX(x,SEQUENCE(y-1,,2)),
          a,INDEX(x,SEQUENCE(y-1)),
          b,z-a,
         arr1,FILTER(a,MIN(b)=b),
         arr2,FILTER(z,MIN(b)=b),
         xml,"<t><s>" &TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE, arr1 & "</s><s>" & arr2)&"</s></t>",
         FILTERXML(xml,"//s"))
```

[image]

For earlier versions of Excel, one way to do this, without developing an extremely long and ungainly formula, is to use **Name**d formulas.

In the Names below, `myRange` refers to the data source, which is expected to be in a single column, and the other names derive from that

```
| myRange | Refers to: | =Sheet1!$A$1:$A$16                                                              |
|---------|------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| x       | Refers to: | =SMALL(myRange,ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,1):INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,COUNT(myRange))))   |
| y       | Refers to: | =ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,1):INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,COUNT(x)-1))                      |
| b       | Refers to: | =INDEX(x,y+1)-INDEX(x,y)                                                        |
| minB    | Refers to: | =MIN(b)                                                                         |
| rws     | Refers to: | =ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,MATCH(minB,b,0)):INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,MATCH(minB,b,0)+1)) |
```

Since the data is numeric, we can `SORT` using the `SMALL` function.
The various `ROW(INDEX:...` constructs mimic the `SEQUENCE` function.

Given the above named formulas, to return the same results as the `LET` function above, you can now use:

```
=INDEX(x,rws)
```

I'm not 100% sure if it will work in older versions. I ran into an oddity in that I was not able to get the proper answer from `=MIN(b)` when entered on the worksheet; but it does return the proper answer when entered as a `Name`d formula (where `minB` refers to `Min(b)`.  So not certain about older Excel versions.

Also it may be the case in older versions of Excel that to enter/confirm this **array formula**, you may have to hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

Comment: nice use of `LET()`

Comment: What a boss of an answer. Sorting is key. If you dont sort you must do subtraction for all combinations (difficult). By sorting your "similar" values will already be next to each other. Very nice. Need O365 but hey its 2021 after all.